# How to to run custom script when as subscriber role user is logged in

Tags: wordpress

I have problem with my scripts when I'm logged in as subscribe role. My custom javascripts is running perfect when I'm logged in as admin role, but when I sign in as user/subscriber role then it not working. I was spent lot of hours and tried everything wp_register_script() and wp_enqueue_script(). Manually insert under footer, and still not working under user. What am I missing ? is there something I forgot or do I need to trigger some setting for user permissions.

```
function woldike_scripts() 
{
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery_js', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js',null, null,true);
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js',null,null,true);
    wp_enqueue_script('custom_collapse', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/collapse.js',null,null,true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'woldike_scripts');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I found the solution to my problem. 
I was need to load dashicons frontend in wordpress and it was so simple to adding this code to functions. `wp_enqueue_style( 'dashicons' );`

Answer (score 0):

Try this script

```
function woldike_scripts() 
{
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery_js', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js', array(), false, false);
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), false, false);
    wp_enqueue_script('custom_collapse', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/collapse.js', array(), false, false);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'woldike_scripts');
```

Comment: Hi, Didn't help. was hoped that was solution.

Comment: Its working fine for subscriber. There is some other issue on your code. any error on console?

Comment: Are you using any minifier or cache plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my header scripting [Screendump of my header in wp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgdDM.png)